# Grouping in PrimeFaces selectCheckboxMenu?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Is there a way to apply grouping (similar to `p:selectOneMenu`) on `p:selectCheckboxMenu`?
I've tried following to add grouping to `p:selectCheckboxMenu`:
**TestBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean {

    List<SelectItem> items;
    String selectedItem;
    List<String> selectedItems;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        SelectItemGroup g1 = new SelectItemGroup("German Cars");
        g1.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{
            new SelectItem("BMW", "BMW"),
            new SelectItem("Mercedes", "Mercedes"),
            new SelectItem("Volkswagen", "Volkswagen")});

        SelectItemGroup g2 = new SelectItemGroup("American Cars");
        g2.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{
            new SelectItem("Chrysler", "Chrysler"),
            new SelectItem("GM", "GM"),
            new SelectItem("Ford", "Ford")});

        items = new ArrayList();
        items.add(g1);
        items.add(g2);
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

**test.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
    <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Select Cars..." value="#{testBean.selectedItems}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.items}" />  
    </p:selectCheckboxMenu> 
</h:form>
```

But in the output it only displays `German Cars` and `American Cars` (the titles of `SelectItemGroup` objects) in the `checkboxMenu`

Comment: same for me, did you solved?

Comment: @tyranitar i couldn't solve it unfortunately!

Comment: Probably this feature will be in PrimeFaces 6.0 that will be available soon (second of May) https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/500

Comment: Thanks @tyranitar! That would be really great! Although its very late but its never too late! :)